# Why is there extra space around pseudo elements?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-animations, pseudo-element

I'm using the pseudo elements ::after and ::before for an animation on my buttons. I have reproduced this problem on 3 different platforms. It's hard to see but there's extra space on the corners. Zooming in makes it a bit easier to see.

I'm using Bootstrap but I've reproduced this with and without Bootstrap.

http://codepen.io/sinrise/pen/vLaGzN

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-action">Test Button</button>
```

Normal
[image: Button-normal state]

Hover
[image: Button-hover state]

Comment: Do you mean why it does not cover the border? ... Please make an image, zoomed in, which show exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the transform3d transition for hover pseudo class and add `height: 100%;` for ::before and ::after pseudo selector targeting the hover animation you wanted to use.

```
a.btn-action {
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: black;
    transition: color 0.4s;
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
a.btn-action::before, a.btn-action::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
   transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
   z-index: -1;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

a.btn-action:hover::before, 
a.btn-action:hover::after {
    height:100%;
}
```

Modified Demo: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/femkhan/pen/rxrMzj)

Comment: Tested and fixed now. overflow hidden was causing the issue. Updated the Code now

Comment: Thanks! That's beautiful and perfect! It works great. Thanks so much!

Comment: If you check the codepen again which i have created with z-index:1 [Codepen](http://codepen.io/femkhan/pen/rxrMzj)

Answer (score 2):

**Updated**

Made some more testing and research and found the real issue ... remove the `z-index: 1;` from the `a.btn-action` rule

```
a.btn-action {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: black;
    transition: color 0.4s;
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
```

[Updated codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZJEmW?editors=1100)

Comment: Thanks, but that completely ruins the animation.

Comment: @sinrise Updated my answer

Comment: Cool. That does seem to fix the issue in the Codepen but unfortunately the z-index property is necessary in my actual project. I tried removing the z-index from the anchor and putting it on it's parent. That removes the extra space on the right but then there's extra space on the left! (it's just the corners in the pen.)

I've messed around with adding a background to the btn div on hover and delaying it but it's so hacky. This must just be another CSS bug?